# Assets not showing files in backend

Tags: assets, add-on-development, pixelandtonic, javascript, fieldtype

I'm building a custom fieldtype that uses **Assets**. So far, I've implemented **Assets.Sheet**, as described here: http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/developers/sheet.html.

But when the Sheet slides into view, **Assets tries to refresh** the files, and **no files are being shown**. There are **no JS errors** and the thumbnail list is emty (checked the html code). Only a console message from **garnish-0.1.min.js** saying: "**Double-instantiating a select on an element**".

The sheet does work properly with any other standard Assets field, but not with my fieldtype.

Here's a screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/3b2D2t1I3g0f

Anybody any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Take a look at the network tab in the dev console - is Assets firing off an Ajax request and what is it getting back as a response?

Comment: There are two ajax calls each time the Sheet tries to refresh. There is no error. But the result is not containing any thumbnails. The result below.
css: ""
html: "<div class="assets-thumbview">↵ <ul>↵   </ul>↵ <div style="clear: left;"></div>↵</div>↵"
requestId: "3"
total: 0

Comment: Diedrik, is it possible to gain access to the site in question? If so, shoot an email to support@pixelandtonic.com with the credentials :)

Comment: @AndrisSevcenko Done, some hours ago on a rainy Belgian morning. ;-)

Comment: I've got a Error when using the search in the Sheet. Hope it helps: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::result() in <b>/data/sites/web/gentsbe/subsites/isis/system/expressionengine/third_party/assets/libraries/assets_lib.php</b> on line <b>693</b><br />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a lot of help from @AndrisSevcenko from Pixel & Tonic, the issues have been resolved. Mostly caused by the code I wrote, a small fix was added to Assets and will be added to the next release.

Thanks again Andris!

Comment: I'd sure be curious to see what the solution was as I'm running in to the same error message.